# How to unify (under the same ID) google analytics visitor data with CRM customer data

Tags: google-analytics, dynamics-crm, crm

How to unify (under the same ID) google analytics visitor data with CRM customer data.

Considering the following:
The data of a Google Analytics visitor and the customer in CRM must belong to the same person.

** I have not been able to find any company that can unify / merge this data so that it can all be centralized in a CRM or similar system.

Answer (score 0):

Has User-ID functionality been proposed?
When the user is logged on the website, the CRM passes the ID of the user to Google Analytics.